# how do i get unity back? "It seems that you do not have the hardware required to run Unity. Please choose Ubuntu Classic"

Tags: unity, boot, video, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I activate Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37651/how-can-i-activate-unity)

restart computer(using ubuntu 11.4) and see this "It seems that you do not have the hardware required to run Unity. Please choose Ubuntu Classic"
how do i get unity back? oh and unity worked for like two or three days before this happened..

Comment: Besides aneal's comment (what I expect to be your solution) also have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36574/freeze-at-startup-it-seems-that-you-do-not-have-the-hardware-required-to-run-ub

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. but it was solved soon after reinstalling graphics card driver. i hope it works for u too.

Comment: it worked for me. Though, there can be other solution without reinstalling the driver. its hassle process if you have nvidia updated version.